# To handle Session expires exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-timeout

I am using `Session` variable throughout in my application and my timeout is 1 hour. Here I need to catch the exception for session expires in any global way across my application. Could anyone help for this.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

On the top your page load, you can look for the session expiration.

```
if(Session["SomeValue"] == null)
   Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");//Session Expired.
```

Alternatively you can redirect to a handler, that would perform your desired operation when session expiration is found.

Answer (score 1):

in the page_load event of you page or in master page write the following code,

```
if (Session["key"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Login_Page_Name");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in session_end event in global.asax file. Also make sure you have checked before using sesison variables like

```
if (Session["YourKey"]!=null)
{
    //do something

}
```